# Transparent background using ImageSharps BinaryThreshold

Tags: imagesharp

Looking at the source code for BinaryThreshold in the ImageSharp library, there are properties for the upper and lower threshold colours [BinaryThresholdProcessor.cs](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/blob/master/src/ImageSharp/Processing/Processors/Binarization/BinaryThresholdProcessor.cs).

I'd like to make an image that instead of having a white background, has a transparent one for the lower threshold. If I had access to these properties I could do that. Is there any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely correct. The underpinnings were there for allowing such behaviour but the functionality was not enabled.

On the back of your question I've updated all the thresholding/dithering code in the library to allow what you need.

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/pull/456

Once merged, this will be in the nightly builds available from Myget. We have a beta3 scheduled very soon for Nuget also.